# How can I find my DHCP server?

Tags: networking, dhcp

On my LAN there are multiple DHCP servers running, and all of them are on the same range.

Now I use a machine which has a dynamic IP address from a DHCP server. I have to know from which server it comes.

How to do that?!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To find out the DHCP server that's giving you the IP, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard  to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
cat /var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases
```

Or you can just use grep command to get DHCP server address.

```
grep dhcp-server-identifier /var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases
```

OR

```
grep dhcp-server-identifier /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases
```

For Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, and 17.10 you can use:

```
dhclient -d -nw eth0
```

Sample output:

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/eth0/00:0c:29:49:3e:67
Sending on   LPF/eth0/00:0c:29:49:3e:67
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x4f723f9)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.138.136 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x4f723f9)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.138.136 from 192.168.138.254
DHCPACK of 192.168.138.136 from 192.168.138.254
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
bound to 192.168.138.136 -- renewal in 892 seconds.
```

Comment: And 14.04 as well!

Comment: @ScottStensland  Added info for later versions of Ubuntu.  Thanks

Comment: @OrganicMarble Added info for later versions of Ubuntu.  Thanks

Comment: Running `dhclient` (i.e., `dhclient -d -nw eth0`) messed with an already running `dhclient` process in my case, resulting in a new IP address.

Answer (score 12):

In Ubuntu 14.04, the `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` is empty. The actual lease file can be found on the command line of `dhclient` via `ps`. Look for the `-lf` option. This command should work in Ubuntu 14.04 installations *(still valid as of 17.10)*:

```
cat $(ps aux | grep -o '[/]var/lib/NetworkManager/\S*.lease') | grep dhcp-server-identifier
```

Comment: On 18.04 `dhclient.leases` isn't empty.

Answer (score 9):

With:

- [**nmap**](https://nmap.org/) ([source](https://superuser.com/a/1114078/500826); [DHCPv6](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/broadcast-dhcp6-discover.html)):

  ```sh
  sudo nmap --script broadcast-dhcp-discover -e eth0  # DHCPv4
  sudo nmap --script broadcast-dhcp6-discover -6      # DHCPv6
  ```
- [**dhdump**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dhcpdump) ([source](https://serverfault.com/a/739250)):

  ```
  sudo dhcpdump -i eth0
  ```
- [**tcpdump**](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html) ([source](https://superuser.com/a/750586/500826)):

  ```
  sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -nev udp port 68
  ```

Others:

- [`dhcp_probe`](https://www.net.princeton.edu/software/dhcp_probe/) (`dhcp-probe` package)

Comment: These are very nice! Could you provide nmap command for IPv6's DHCP?

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu 16.04 you can try

```
journalctl | grep DHCPACK
```

Comment: This works with `dhclient`, does it work [with systemd-networkd](https://askubuntu.com/a/1047654/349837)?

Answer (score 1):

Using the new [iproute2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2) (in my case in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS):

```
$ ip route | grep default

default via 1xx.1xx.xxx.xxx dev gpd0 metric 10 
default via 192.168.xxx.xxx dev wlp0s proto dhcp metric 100
```

The DHCP server IP is the one given after the `via` keyword for each of your specified network interface(s).

`ip r | grep default` also works.

From the man:

```
ip route
   Show table routes.
```

The help:

```
$ ip route help

$ ip route help
Usage: ip route { list | flush } SELECTOR
       ip route save SELECTOR
       ip route restore
       ip route showdump
       ip route get [ ROUTE_GET_FLAGS ] ADDRESS
                            [ from ADDRESS iif STRING ]
                            [ oif STRING ] [ tos TOS ]
                            [ mark NUMBER ] [ vrf NAME ]
                            [ uid NUMBER ] [ ipproto PROTOCOL ]
                            [ sport NUMBER ] [ dport NUMBER ]
       ip route { add | del | change | append | replace } ROUTE
SELECTOR := [ root PREFIX ] [ match PREFIX ] [ exact PREFIX ]
            [ table TABLE_ID ] [ vrf NAME ] [ proto RTPROTO ]
            [ type TYPE ] [ scope SCOPE ]
ROUTE := NODE_SPEC [ INFO_SPEC ]
NODE_SPEC := [ TYPE ] PREFIX [ tos TOS ]
             [ table TABLE_ID ] [ proto RTPROTO ]
             [ scope SCOPE ] [ metric METRIC ]
             [ ttl-propagate { enabled | disabled } ]
INFO_SPEC := { NH | nhid ID } OPTIONS FLAGS [ nexthop NH ]...
NH := [ encap ENCAPTYPE ENCAPHDR ] [ via [ FAMILY ] ADDRESS ]
      [ dev STRING ] [ weight NUMBER ] NHFLAGS
FAMILY := [ inet | inet6 | mpls | bridge | link ]
OPTIONS := FLAGS [ mtu NUMBER ] [ advmss NUMBER ] [ as [ to ] ADDRESS ]
           [ rtt TIME ] [ rttvar TIME ] [ reordering NUMBER ]
           [ window NUMBER ] [ cwnd NUMBER ] [ initcwnd NUMBER ]
           [ ssthresh NUMBER ] [ realms REALM ] [ src ADDRESS ]
           [ rto_min TIME ] [ hoplimit NUMBER ] [ initrwnd NUMBER ]
           [ features FEATURES ] [ quickack BOOL ] [ congctl NAME ]
           [ pref PREF ] [ expires TIME ] [ fastopen_no_cookie BOOL ]
TYPE := { unicast | local | broadcast | multicast | throw |
          unreachable | prohibit | blackhole | nat }
TABLE_ID := [ local | main | default | all | NUMBER ]
SCOPE := [ host | link | global | NUMBER ]
NHFLAGS := [ onlink | pervasive ]
RTPROTO := [ kernel | boot | static | NUMBER ]
PREF := [ low | medium | high ]
TIME := NUMBER[s|ms]
BOOL := [1|0]
FEATURES := ecn
ENCAPTYPE := [ mpls | ip | ip6 | seg6 | seg6local | rpl | ioam6 ]
ENCAPHDR := [ MPLSLABEL | SEG6HDR | SEG6LOCAL | IOAM6HDR ]
SEG6HDR := [ mode SEGMODE ] segs ADDR1,ADDRi,ADDRn [hmac HMACKEYID] [cleanup]
SEGMODE := [ encap | inline ]
SEG6LOCAL := action ACTION [ OPTIONS ] [ count ]
ACTION := { End | End.X | End.T | End.DX2 | End.DX6 | End.DX4 |
            End.DT6 | End.DT4 | End.DT46 | End.B6 | End.B6.Encaps |
            End.BM | End.S | End.AS | End.AM | End.BPF }
OPTIONS := OPTION [ OPTIONS ]
OPTION := { srh SEG6HDR | nh4 ADDR | nh6 ADDR | iif DEV | oif DEV |
            table TABLEID | vrftable TABLEID | endpoint PROGNAME }
IOAM6HDR := trace prealloc type IOAM6_TRACE_TYPE ns IOAM6_NAMESPACE size IOAM6_TRACE_SIZE
ROUTE_GET_FLAGS := [ fibmatch ]
```

Current version:

```
$ ip -V
ip utility, iproute2-5.15.0, libbpf 0.5.0
```

More:
Web: https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2
Git.kernel: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git
Github: https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2