# systemd-networkd daemon does not start the DHCP client

Tags: networking, systemd

I have the appropriate network file with DHCP enabled.

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/network/20-dhcp.network 
[Match]
Name=enp3*

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4

[DHCP]
UseDomains=true
```

I have appropriate /etc/resolv.conf as well. I am not using systemd-resolvd daemon (and it may not have anything to do with it, because I did try using it, but did not help anyway).
Any ideas why the DHCP client needs to be run manually to get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that I had two network files. I followed arch linux systemd-networkd documentation (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-networkd#Wireless_adapter), and created one network file:

```
/etc/systemd/network/25-wireless.network
[Match]
Name=wlp2s0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
```

And it is working.

Answer (score 13):

Just in case people aren't aware - `systemd-networkd` now contains its own in-built DHCP client implementation so no external DHCP clients would be started unless they're configured elsewhere.

The configuration is controlled by a number of configuration files as described in the [systemd-networkd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/systemd-networkd.service.8.html) man page. Since Ubuntu 18.04 the network configuration (`/{lib,etc,run}/netplan/*.yaml`) is now controlled by [netplan](https://netplan.io/) which will generate configuration files for systemd-networkd (`/{lib,etc,run}/systemd/network/`).

Specifically the DHCP client operation is controlled in the [systemd.network](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/systemd.network.5.html) config file - it can be enabled in the `[NETWORK]` section of the config file using the `DHCP` directive (it defaults to "no") and configured the `[DHCP]` section. Note it is also possible to enable DHCPServer mode but that is generally mutually exclusive to DHCP client mode.

Comment: Welcome , could you explain  the built-in dhcp in `systemd-network`  , please.

Comment: i did everything that was asked to be done, configuring a bridge (netdev) and a network-file with DHCPServer=yes and DHCP=ipv4, but it won't work! the guest has no DHCP and receives no IP/DNS information

Comment: I've updated the question to explain that enabling `DHCPServer` mode would probably result in DHCP client mode being disabled. If you want the DHCP client mode you only need to set the `DHCP` variable in the `[NETWORK]` config section.

Answer (score 6):

From reading `man systemd.network`, it sounds like the `.network` files in `/etc/systemd/network` are controlled by `systemd-networkd`.  If the files aren't being read, it could be that you aren't using this part of `systemd`.

For example, on a Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, I can see that `systemd-networkd` is not in use:

```
 systemctl status systemd-networkd
```

● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)

Instead, the `NetworkManager` service is running. So, a DHCP client would be configured through NetworkManager in that case, or NetworkManager needs to be stopped and disabled, and `systemd-networkd` needs to be started and enabled.

Comment: Yes, systemd-netword is enabled and running. I had uninstalled NetworkManager before migrating to systemd-networkd

Comment: I've now added some more info on configuration.